# Linker error when linking Cocoa Touch Framework to Today Extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

The current project I'm working on has an iOS component, as well as a Today Extension which have a bit of a overlap in UI components.

I created a cocoa touch framework containing the duplicated UI elements as a new target in the project, and added it to the **Link Binary with Libraries** build phase of both the app and extension.

I'm able to build Debug builds fine, but when Archiving a release build I get the following error.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_MyClass", referenced from: someFile
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
```

and the same error for armv7 as well.

I've tried to find a solution by playing with the build settings but have had no luck so far.

[Current build settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TV7yM.png)

**EDIT**

I figured out what the issue was.
I had the "symbols hidden by default" compilation flag set to **YES**.

Comment: Is the library (and all of its components) being built in the release build or only for debug build?

Comment: Thanks for the response @Tim It's being built for both.

Comment: Looks like the implementation file containing `MyClass` (`MyClass.m`?) has not been added to any of the Xcode targets.

Comment: @trojanfoe I've double checked that as well, and it is added to the Cocoa Touch Framework that I created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the issue was.
I had the "symbols hidden by default" compilation flag set to **YES**.